# Render two radio buttons on different positions in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

I am using bootstrap Vue to create a radio button based form component. Since I can define all the options of the radio button at once, I am facing difficulty in incorporating other controls between two radio buttons

For e.g. there are two radio buttons: "2 wheeler" and "4 wheeler".
On click of 2 wheeler i want to show some field(say F1) and similarly another field for 4 wheeler as well.
Now the only restriction is that both radio buttons shouldn't be inline and the fileds (F1) should be horizontally between both these radio buttons. 
Is there a way to do this with bootstrap Vue?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: please show your code.